# can't use css file zf2 (Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for inlineStyle)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, helper, inline-styles

I have a css and js files, i want to use it and call it from controller, for js these lines work perfectly:

$serverUrl = $this->baseUrl();
$headScript = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('inlineScript');
$headScript->appendFile($serverUrl . '/assets/js/file.js');

But for css when i use these lines :

```
 $serverUrl = $this->baseUrl();
     $headScript = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('inlineStyle');
     $headScript->appendFile($serverUrl . '/assets/js/file.css');
```

i have this error:

Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for inlineStyle

Answer (score 0):

Try to use “headLink” instead of “inlineStyle”.